# MySQL: How to get "this week's date" using the current date?

Tags: php, sql, date

I have this SQL query about getting the 5 events today:

```
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.title, nr.body, nr.teaser, FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_start) start_date, FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_end) end_date
FROM node n
LEFT JOIN event e ON n.nid = e.nid
LEFT JOIN node_revisions nr ON nr.nid = e.nid
WHERE n.`type` = 'event'
AND NOW() BETWEEN FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_start) AND FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_end)
ORDER BY n.`created` DESC
LIMIT 5
```

Then I need to get the "this week's event" using "a week that includes "today" and starts on a Sunday".

How can I do that in MySQL?

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define "this week" better -- do you mean a 7-days sliding window centered on today, or a week (the one that includes "today") starting e.g. on a Sunday?  That's entirely dependent on the semantics of "this week" and it's impossible for us to decide what you meant by said ambiguous expression.  Of the two approaches you mention, one or the other (or a variant thereon) will be appropriate depending on your meaning.

**Edit**: the OP has clarified in a comment that he means "a week that includes "today" and starts on a Sunday" -- and I deduce from his use of `FROM_UNIXTIME` that the specific SQL dialect he's targeting is MySQL.  Then, `WEEK(somedate, 0)` is the MySQL function that should give him exactly what he wants, see [mysql's docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week).

Specifically,

```
AND WEEK(CURDATE, 0) BETWEEN WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_start), 0)
                         AND WEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(e.event_end), 0)
```

should be the `WHERE` clause the OP is looking for.

Comment: Hi Alex, sorry for my imcomplete question because I am not sure as well but I confirmed it and the correct one is "a week that includes "today" and starts on a Sunday" :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex! :D It worked. I am not familiar with the WEEK() function until now. It works now. Cheers :)

Comment: @Christian, glad you liked it!  @marknt15, always happy to help.

Comment: Um Alex, I have a follow up question. I am trying to get all records for this month. I have this query but doesn't work. What do you think the error is?
SELECT n.nid, n.type, n.title 
FROM node n
WHERE n.`type` = 'event'
AND CURDATE() <= LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) 
AND CURDATE() > DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()), interval 1 day)
ORDER BY n.`created` DESC
LIMIT 5

Thanks again.

Comment: How can today be less than a month ago or more than tomorrow? That's what you're testing, not anything about the database... three times curdate in the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is for SQL Server or MySQL, but in MySQL you could get the current [weekday](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) of today and then use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) to subtract that many days from the current date (start date) then using start date, use [date_add](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) again to add 7 days (end date).

Hopefully that helps, let me know if you need help with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the table/column names, it appears you're working with Drupal. Have you considered using a View to achieve your goal? I can't tell from the context whether this is part of a module you're writing, in which case keep plugging away, or whether you just want a list of events to display in a block, in which case a View should be able to do all this for you without messing around with PHP/SQL.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have that option, but for performance reasons it could be better to do the date calculations in your program code. If you use a function on a column in a WHERE clause, MySQL cannot use indexes. A simple example: http://netfactory.dk/2004/12/13/mysql-date-functions-and-indexes/
Most languages should have decent functions/libraries for date/time manipulation.